# Getting this error just after I upgrade FLUTTER to the latest version using IntelliJ terminal

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-dependencies

Upgraded FLUTTER and this is what I get after I try to run my project.

[image]

Comment: Please copy the error as text to your question instead of linking to a screenshot.

Comment: Have you restarted intelliJ? also try restarting the system, then run `flutter packages get` in your project directory from terminal.